# How to create defect automatically in jira for the failed build on Bamboo?

Tags: jira, bamboo

We want to create a defect/task in Jira automatically for a failed build in Bamboo. And need to assign this defect to the person who broke the build.

How to do these two things?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open JIRA issue regarding this -- [BAM-2537](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-2537) -- watch it, vote for it - maybe they'll add it to the product.

The comments from [Top 5 Reasons Creating JIRA Issues from Bamboo Makes Your Team Awesome-r](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2012/06/create-jira-issues-from-bamboo/) also discuss what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Atlassian CLI. There's already a good answer on StackOverflow.

[Can Bamboo change status of tickets in JIRA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505433/can-bamboo-change-status-of-tickets-in-jira/16594231#16594231)

This is not "out of the box" solution, of course, and requires some additional work.